# chain transitive

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $X$ is a metric space with metric d and $f:X\to X$ is a continuous map.we call $(X,f)$ is dynamical system.dynamical system $(X,f)$ is **topological transitive** if for any pair of nonempty open sets $U,V\subseteq X$, there is an $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ such that $f^n(U)\cap V\neq \emptyset$. Recall that for $\delta > 0$ and $x,y \in X$, a **$\delta$-chain** of $f$ from $x$ to $y$ of length $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a finite sequence $\{x_{0}=x,x_{1},...,x_n=y\}$ satisfying $d(f(x_i),x_{i+1})<\delta$ for $0\leq i\leq n-1$. $(X,f)$ is said to be **chain transitive** if for any $\delta>0$ and any pair $x,y\in X$, there is a $\delta-$chain of $f$ from $x$ to $y$.

> **Lemma**:A topological transitive is chain transitive.
>   please proof this lemma.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Given $x,y,\delta$ look at $U,V$ being balls with center at $x$ and $y$, respectively, and with radius $<\delta/2$. Take the corresponding $n$ from the definition of topologically transitive and build $x_0=x, x_k=f^{k}(x)$. Show that $f^{n}(x)$ is in the ball with center $y$ and radius $\delta$ (Triangle inequality).

Answer (score 0):

suppose $\delta> 0$, $x ,y\in X$, let $U=B(f(x),\delta)$ and $V=B(y,\delta)$, $f$ is topological transitive, so there is $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $f^n(U)\cap V\neq\emptyset$, so there is $\alpha\in U$ such that $d(f^n(\alpha),y)<\delta$ and $d(f(x),\alpha)<\delta$. Finite sequence $\{\alpha_0=x,\alpha_1=\alpha,...,\alpha_k=f^k(\alpha),...,\alpha_{n-1}=f^{n-1}(\alpha),\alpha_n=y\}$ is enough for definition of chain transitive.